# woocommerce изменить название статуса заказа

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Здравствуйте, подскажите пожалуйста, как можно изменить название статуса заказа в админ-панели, например статус заказа `обработка` изменить на `новый заказ` тут:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и тут:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

какой самый оптимальный способ это сделать, ну и так, чтобы это не слетело с обновлением?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте фильтр wc_order_statuses

```
function wc_order_statuses_filter( $order_statuses ) {
    // Измените $order_statuses, например
    $order_statuses['wc-processing'] => 'Новый заказ';
    return $order_statuses;
}
add_filter( 'wc_order_statuses', 'wc_order_statuses_filter' );
```

По умолчанию статусы - это такой массив:

```
$order_statuses = array(
    'wc-pending'    => _x( 'Pending payment', 'Order status', 'woocommerce' ),
    'wc-processing' => _x( 'Processing', 'Order status', 'woocommerce' ),
    'wc-on-hold'    => _x( 'On hold', 'Order status', 'woocommerce' ),
    'wc-completed'  => _x( 'Completed', 'Order status', 'woocommerce' ),
    'wc-cancelled'  => _x( 'Cancelled', 'Order status', 'woocommerce' ),
    'wc-refunded'   => _x( 'Refunded', 'Order status', 'woocommerce' ),
    'wc-failed'     => _x( 'Failed', 'Order status', 'woocommerce' ),
);
```